# How do I remove/uninstall a program that I have complied from source?

Tags: package-management

How do I remove a program that I have compiled from source using the `./configure; make; make install` method?  Does it matter whether I have kept the original directory that the source was stored in or not?

Comment: `make uninstall`? But you need to keep Makefile.

Comment: You don't really need to keep the makefile if you've just done a straight configure, you can just configure again and `make uninstall`.

Comment: Install them with a custom prefix/DESTDIR into your home directory; do not let the makefile run as root. If using a Debian or Redhat-based Linux flavor, better still, use `fpm` and the package manager shipped with the distro.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

There are a couple of approaches that you can pursue.

1. Re-run `./configure` with the same options you originally passed to it and then run `make uninstall`. If you no longer have the original files, re-download the tarball of the corresponding version and use that.
2. Use `find` or `locate` to track down the relevant files (only really practicable for smaller programmes) and remove them manually.

To avoid this scenario again, you could always look at a tool like [checkinstall](http://asic-linux.com.mx/~izto/checkinstall/) for building from source and tracking the installed files; it was developed for precisely this reason:

> A lot of people has asked me how can they remove from their boxes a program they compiled and installed from source. Some times -very few- the program's author adds an uninstall rule to their Makefile, but that's not usually the case. This is my primary reason to write CheckInstall. After you ./configure; make your program, CheckInstall will run make install (or whatever you tell it to run) and keep track of every file modified by this installation.

Comment: Disagree with Mr. CheckInstall vis, "sometimes -very few- the program's author adds an uninstall rule".  Some of them don't, but I think most of them do. They've already had to deal with their own tish over and over again, which is a pretty good motive.

Comment: Best bet is to create a proper package for your system. That way the package manager is aware of the program, tracks dependencies, and can uninstall cleanly.